# Self-referential Generic Types

Tags: java, generics, covariance

Consider this example:

```
public final class Main<T extends Main<T>> {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main<?> main = new Main<>();
    }
}
```

This compiles perfectly. However when I try to make this compile without using the diamond, the only way I can get it to work is by using a raw type.

```
Main<?> main = new Main();
```

Attempts without raw types don't work:

```
Main<?> main = new Main<?>();              // None of
Main<?> main = new Main<Main<?>>();        // these
Main<?> main = new Main<Main<Main<?>>>();  // compile
```

So why does the original version with the diamond work? What is the inferred type when you write `Main<?> main = new Main<>();` ?

Is it inferring a raw type, or is it inferring some kind of infinitely nested type like this?

```
Main<Main<Main<Main<...>>>>
```

Comment: I kind of think you should replace `Main` with `Buffalo` in this post.

Comment: So, you've invented the endless recursion in the Java Compiler. Nice job, like it!

Comment: `Enum` has a similar declaration, so what you're encountering is nothing new.

Comment: I don't think you _can_ explicitly specify the diamond type without extending `Main` with a `Foo extends Main<Foo>`.  I don't think the inferred type is syntactically representable.  I don't think it's infinitely nested, but I think it's a magic `? extends Main<?>` where the `?`s are magically the same `?`.

Comment: @Makoto The difference is that `Enum` is `abstract`. The standard self-referential types in the language (e.g. `Enum`, `Comparator` are `abstract`). A concrete self referential type is a very weird thing.

Comment: As far as I can tell everything in your code makes sense and just creates something unusable together undetectable by the compiler. Like writing `if (Boolean.FALSE) { }`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I think you're probably right. I was just hoping that somebody would confirm that there really are these weird syntactically unrepresentable types the compiler uses. It must be in the specification somewhere.

Comment: I don't actually know how something like `List<?> = new List<>()` would work, which seems to be the only mysterious part to me at least.

Comment: @djechlin At least in that case you can just imagine that the compiler is able to substitute `Object`.

Comment: @djechlin: It's not unusable; it's just covariant (meaning that the type parameter is not very usable).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `?` in `Main<?>` is a placeholder that may be any type at bind-time.

Each `?` that you write in source may be a different type (referred to in error messages as `capture#2-of ?`), so you cannot assign an expression of `Main<?>` to a variable of any expressible type.

The diamond operator works here because its type inference runs after the `?`s are captured – your `Main<>` becomes not `Main<?>` but `Main<capture#1 of ?>` (assuming the `Main<?>` you assign it to is `capture#1`).

In other words, the diamond operator is the only syntax that can directly specify a specific capture, just like `var` in C# is the only syntax that can directly specify an anonymous type.  (note that overload resolution with method type inference can also resolve to specific captures)

---

As for what the code means, `new Main<?>()` (for any capture of `?`) is shorthand for `Main<? extends Object>`, or, in your case, `Main<? extends Main<same ?>>` (the compiler automatically constrains the `?` to the constraints of the type).  This becomes a covariant view of `Main<>`, where the type parameter is convertible only to `Main<?>` (since it may actually be any type, so you can't assume anything beyond the constraint).

Usually, there is no reason to actually create such a thing.

Comment: So the compiler can create an artificial type `capture#1` that extends `Main<capture#1>` even though there isn't a real type like that?

Comment: @PaulBoddington: That's not a type, but a constraint (just like `List<? extends SomeInterface & OtherInterface>`)

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to make something that compiles without the diamond operator, by using a generic helper method (but of course, this then begs the question, what type argument is being inferred for the call to the helper method):

```
final class Main<T extends Main<T>> {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main<?> main = helper();
    }
    private static <T extends Main<T>> Main<T> helper() {
        return new Main<T>();
    }
}
```